# Finding list entry with the highest count

Tags: haskell

I have an `Entry` data type

```
data Entry = Entry {
    count :: Integer,
    name :: String }
```

Then I want to write a function, that takes the name and a list of `Entry`s as arguments an give me the `Entry`s with the highest count.  What I have so far is

```
searchEntry :: String -> [Entry] -> Maybe Integer
searchEntry _ [] = Nothing
searchEntry name1 (x:xs) = 
   if name x == name1
       then Just (count x)
       else searchEntry name xs
```

That gives me the FIRST `Entry` that the function finds, but I want the `Entry` with the highest count. How can I implement that?

Comment: Of course it gives you the first entry, it's called `searchEntry` and does exactly that! Closing, because you're apparently asking for an implementation of said function without any tries whatsoever.

Comment: I would recommend clarifying your title as well, since it has nothing to do with your question beyond using the `Maybe` type.

Comment: You need to traverse the entire list for finding the highest count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to break the problem into two parts:

1. Find all entries matching a given name
2. Find the entry with the highest count

You could set it up as

```
entriesByName :: String -> [Entry] -> [Entry]
entriesByName name entries = undefined

-- Use Maybe since the list might be empty
entryWithHighestCount :: [Entry] -> Maybe Entry
entryWithHighestCount entries = undefined

entryByNameWithHighestCount :: String -> [Entry] -> Maybe Entry
entryByNameWithHighestCount name entires = entryWithHighestCount $ entriesByName name entries
```

All you have to do is implement the relatively simple functions that are used to implement `getEntryByNameWithHighestCount`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an inner method that takes a current result as a parameter and returns that instead of `Nothing` when reaching the end of the method.

Also you would need to update your result found logic to compare a potentially existing function and the found value.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing the signature of the function to `String->Maybe Entry` (or `String->[Entry]`) if you indeed want to return the "Entry" items with the highest count.

Otherwise, you can actually do what you want as a oneliner using some pretty common Haskell functions....

As Bheklilr mentioned, the name filter can be done first, and it is really easy to do this using the `filter` function....

```
filter (hasName theName) entries
```

Note that `hasName` can be written out fully as a separate function,  but Haskell also offers you the following shortcut.

```
hasName = (== theName) . name
```

Now you just need the maximum value....  Haskell has a `maximum` function, but it only works on the Ord class.  You can make Entry an instance of Ord, or you can just use the related maximumBy function, that takes an extra ordering function

```
maximumBy orderFunction entries2
```

Again, you can write `orderFunction` yourself (which you might want to do as an excercise), but haskell again offers a shortcut.

```
orderFunction = compare `on` count
```

You will need to import some libs to get this all to work (Data.Function, Data.List).  You also will need to put in some extra code to account for the Nothing case.

It might be worth it to write out the functions longhand first, but I recommend that you use Hoogle to lookup and understand `compare`, `on`, and `maximumBy`....  Using tricks like this can really shorten your code.

Putting it all together, you can get the entry with the maximum count like this

```
maxEntry = maximumBy (compare `on` count) $ filter ((theName ==) . name) $ entries
```

You will need to modify this to account for the Nothing case, or if you want to return all max Entries (this just chooses one), or if you really wanted to return count, and not the entry.